# Redirect too many times when using socialite laravel package in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have installed socialite package in my application but its not working properly.

In my login with linkedin button i have given url like below

```
href="{{ url('auth/linkedin') }}"
```

My route file is

```
Route::get('auth/linkedin', 'LinkedInController@redirectToLinkedin');
Route::get('/linkedin/callback', 'LinkedInController@handleLinkedinCallback');
```

LinkedInController.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use Exception;

class LinkedInController extends Controller {
protected $redirectTo = '/';
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

protected function validator(array $data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data) {
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

public function redirectToLinkedin() {
    return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
}

public function handleLinkedinCallback() {
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
        $create['name'] = $user->name;
        $create['email'] = $user->email;
        $create['linkedin_id'] = $user->id;

        $userModel = new User;
        $createdUser = $userModel->addNew($create);
        Auth::loginUsingId($createdUser->id);
        return redirect('/index');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect('auth/linkedin');
    }
}
}
```

After i clicking login with linkedin it will comes to **redirectToLinkedin()** function but i got error like

> This page isn’t working
>      localhost redirected you too many times.
>      Try clearing your cookies.
>      ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Whats a problem with my code?

Comment: When you click then redirectToLinkedin() means catch part?

Comment: The problem is inside your routes for sure, can you paste them?

Comment: well you call `return redirect('auth/linkedin');` on an exception. Since you are already authorized it will simply renavigate to the same method. if your try block is never working you will always have an infinit lopo. better dump this exception and investegate the reason for it.

Comment: Check your dump `catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }`

Comment: I suspect that the `handleLinkedinCallback()` function is throwing an exception so the catch block is repeatedly redirecting back. What happens if you change where the redirect in that catch block goes?

Answer (score 0):

in the .env file there is a LINKEDIN_REDIRECT or something. Make sure that the value is to the callback link not the redirect link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).